# compare two image and find common parts in them asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

hi
I have created web application for simple image comparison by converting to byte. But i want to compare parts whether that part in one image exists in second images.
Anyone can help me.
Thank you

Comment: I think you should drop the web part of your question, the solution will not depend on it being a web or a windows application in any way.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this forum post [here.](http://p2p.wrox.com/c/69490-comparing-two-images-c-without-hash.html)

Basically it sounds like you would be comparing pixel colors for similarity. I bet over time with testing you could improve upon the accuracy of your app.

Comment: I am not comparing images pixel

Comment: It's sounds like you need to take a block bytes and compare other blocks of bytes to see if they are similar. What is similar is something that you need to define. I think that even if you do pull this off, there will be instances where you program says something is similar that you don't agree with. Sounds like a lot of work.